# This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type string

Tags: ocaml

I am new to Ocaml,

I am trying to figure out how to "cast" a "unit" type constant to "string" type.

I've seen there was `string_of_int`function to do so with integer type but cannot find the equivalent for "unit" type. Maybe there is something to do with the [Printf](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html), I did so with boolean using `Printf.printf "%B" (x);` but I haven't figure out what would be the one to use in "unit" type case.

Here is my code example:

Function defined:

`let displayList l = List.iter(fun x -> print_string(string_of_int x^";")) l;;`

Using the function above:

1. The following expression works: `let _ = displayList [5;5;6;5;5;6;3]
   in ();` and displays "5;5;6;5;5;6;3;".
2. The following expression does not work: `let _ = print_string ("[" ^
   displayList [5;5;6;5;5;6;3] ^ "]") in ();`. It throws error message
   "This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of
   type string".

Comment: Carefully write your code on multiple lines, so you can begin to see which exact subexpression is producing the type error.

Comment: Once you see where the error is, you won't want to "cast" `unit` to `string` anymore, but you will see another problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the printed and the returned values.

`displayList` doesn't return a `string`. It prints a `string` and then returns an `unit`. The string concatenation operator (`^`) expects two `string`s, but, as mentioned, the return type of `displayList` is `unit`.

Making a `string` out of `unit` wouldn't do what it seems you are expecting. `displayList` would still print `5;5;6;5;5;6;3;` and your expression would return a string like `"[()]"`.

If you intended to print `[5;5;6;5;5;6;3;]`, a solution (using what you already have) could be

```
let displayList l =
  print_char '[';
  List.iter(fun x -> print_string(string_of_int x^";")) l;
  print_char ']'
;;
```

Comment: Thanks for those clarifications! For the record I ended up with \n `let rec displayListNoBrackets l = 
    if List.length l = 0 then print_string("")
        else if List.length l = 1 then print_string(string_of_int (List.hd l))
        else print_string(string_of_int (List.hd l)^";");
    if List.length l > 0 then displayListNoBrackets (List.tl l);;
\n let displayListWithBrackets l = 
    print_char '[';
    displayListNoBrackets l;
    print_char ']';;` \n then it displays just fine using the function `displayListWithBrackets l`.

Comment: `displayListNoBrackets` does the job, but is doing more work then it needs to. `List.length` takes linear time, so you're traversing  the remaining list on every iteration. You don't need the know the full length to know if a list is empty.

A more idiomatic approach that avoids this problem would be to use `match` as in `let rec displayListNoBrackets l = match l with  | [] -> ...   | head :: tail ->  ...`